# Spark map with conditions / patternmatching

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, rdd

I have an rdd from reading a csv

```
val sampleRDD = sc.textFile(path)
```

The csv looks like this:

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4
    --------------------
    val1 val2 val3 val4
    val5 val6 val7 val8
    val9 val10 val3 val12
    val13 val14 val15 val16
    val17 val18 val3 val20
    val21 val22 val7 val24
```

For col3 I have multiple values that repeat.  I have a mapping.  For `val3` I want the output value to be `A`, for `val7` I want the output value to be `B`.  I want the output to look like the one below.

Unfortunately we still have to use spark 1.0.0 and need to work with RDDs.

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4
    --------------------
    val1 val2 A val4
    val5 val6 B val8
    val9 val10 A val12
    val13 val14 val15 val16
    val17 val18 A val20
    val21 val22 B val24
```

How do I go about doing such transformation

Comment: What have you tried already? There are plenty of examples of such  `map` operation  (*hint*) on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply go by making a UDF and applying on that column :
So your UDF should look something like this:

```
def getValue(s:String)=s match{
case "val13"=>"A"
case "val17"=>"B"
case _=>s
}
```

Then make a udf out of this function

```
val valueUdf= udf(getValue _)
```

And now Apply this UDF to get the new Value output

```
sampleRDD.withColumns("col3",valueUdf(sampleRDD("col3")))
```

This will give your desired result!

P.S: The code is not tested but it must work !